# underscore undefined after using noConflict method

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

Here is the small code I am trying to run using underscore:

```
     var data = [
          {"name": "Romania"},
          {"name": "Virgin Islands, British"},
          {"name": "Gibraltar"},
          {"name": "Bangladesh"},
          {"name": "Taiwan"},
          {"name": "Jamaica"},
          {"name": "Paraguay"},
          {"name": "Reunion"},
          {"name": "Marshall Islands"},
          {"name": "Nepal" },
          { "name": "Ireland" }
        ];

        var namelist = _.pluck(data, "name");
        console.log("list 1 => " + namelist);
        // outputs =>  list 1 => Romania,Virgin Islands, British...

        (function(underscore){
          var u = underscore.noConflict();
          var namelist = u.pluck(data, "name");
          console.log("list 2 => " + namelist);
          // outputs =>  list 2 => Romania,Virgin Islands, British...
        })(_);

        var namelist = _.pluck(data, "name");
        console.log("list 3 => " + namelist);
        // throw an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pluck' of undefined
```

Unlike in jquery we usually use noConflict method avoid conflict between two jquery versions or some other library's $, somehow I do not understand the clear meaning of using **noConflict**

This is what situation I have in my page. Different templates and different syntax, therefore I am trying to use `template` method of `underscore` with different template settings.

Am I doing something wrong? 
How do you get the new instance of underscore without affecting the global variable?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what the question is.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson see the updated snippet. I am trying to figure out why `noConflict` method undefines the global `_` variable.

Comment: Different developers interpretation and implementation of what `noConflict` actually means and does. The underscore library defines is as "when you call `noConflict` you would never want the default global available, so unbind it".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it works as expected.

Comment: I think it's a good question, as the behaviour may not be expected, I can see this being quite useful to people. @DavidBarker summed it up perfectly.

Comment: @DavidBarker thanks it does makes sense, although one more problem arises in mind is, how do I keep the global `_` untouched or get the new instance of underscore inside of self executing function ?

Comment: @Mathletics The question is not about what works or what does not work, I asked it to clear the confusion about the usage of `noConflict` method and how to get a new instance of underscore. :)

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem. `noConflict` doesn't create a new instance, it just unbinds the `_`. Why do you need a new instance?

Answer (score 1):

This works as expected; `noConflict` frees up the default variable so that it can be reassigned *without conflict*.

---

From the docs for [_.noConflict()](http://underscorejs.org/#noConflict)

> Give control of the _ variable back to its previous owner.